# Trouble with ajax and node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I am having a problem that has me perplexed.

I have a simple webpage that works using php and mysql. I am trying to conver this to node.js and mysql.

There are 2 dropdown select boxes the first contains a list of customers that is taken from the database. (This works well)

when a customer is selected I need the second box to contain a list of instruments that belong to the customer.

I have this working great in the php version but in the node.js version the second dropdown does not get up[dated and the console has and error that states
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Does this mean I can not use this code or better yet how do I change this script to make it work properly??

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("select#cust").change(function(){
var cust_id =  $("select#cust option:selected").attr('value'); 
var test =  $("#test").val();
var din = $("#idate").val(); 
$("#inst").html( "" );

if (cust_id.length > 0 ) { 
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "fetch_inst",
        data: "cust_id="+cust_id,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#inst').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
        },
        success: function(data) {    
            $("#inst").html( data );

        }
    });

     }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to fix your script that was already working? If your client-side JavaScript was working before, then that's probably not the problem. Look at the response that comes back from node vs. PHP and figure out what's different between them. You haven't told us anything of substance about either one of them.

Comment: The response in the node.js console is GET /fetch_inst?custid=2368&_=1425395147244  200 59.839 ms the cust_id is correct but I can't understand where the _=1425395147244 is coming from?  Could that be the problem?  In PHP the response is only the cust_id

Comment: The extra _=14253... Is an anti caching mechanism so your responses aren't cached. Please provide the payload that is recieved after the ajax request is submitted.

Comment: The extra `_=` parameter is there because you have the `cache` option set to `false` in your call to `$.ajax()`. jQuery automatically adds a cache buster querystring parameter to GET requests when that option is disabled. See the documentation for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ok so what would help in trying to fix this do I need to post more information and if so what information

Comment: @phpnoobie For starters, you could add some error handling and tell us what kind of errors you're getting. Watch the AJAX requests in your browser's Network tab or in Fiddler to see if there's something wrong with the request. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask